# Can't read file from a C++ program on a Mac

Tags: c++, file-io, readfile, file-not-found

First of all, this is part of my code:

```
....
string input;
getline(cin, input);

ifstream openFile;
openFile.open(input.c_str(), ios::in);

if(openFile.is_open()){
    cout << "File opened" << endl;
}  
else {
    cout << "Cant open the file " << endl;
}
```

The result always "Cant open the file". I am very, very sure that the files are exists. I have data1.txt, data2.txt ... data10.txt in the same directory (I used XCode to add new empty file, add the data inside and save it).

I do another test, I create a new directory, copy paste the cpp and data files. I run in terminal, and it works, it can read the data file. Why does xcode cant read my data files? Any idea?

Comment: Is this about iOS or Mac development ? What's the exact content of `input` ? If it's a relative path, is your process in the correct working directory ?

Comment: Mac, a cpp command line program. THe input can be: data1.txt, data2.txt

Comment: Nothing at all to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the full path to the files. Xcode will run the application from the build directory which is not where the code is.

If the files are copied as part of building an OSX or iOS application you should look at the [bundle structure](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html) to find the directory.

Comment: hmmm.. but i need to past it to others OS environment. Maybe linux?? It wont work again right?

Comment: If this is pure C++ then it will work in all environments but the question is which directories are the executable and files in. The usual way is to pass the filenames in as parameters to the executable and not rely on them being in the same directory

Comment: @ Mark: Yes, it is pure C++. A very basic one. It works if i compile and run it through mac terminal. But in xcode, it just does not work :(

Comment: As my answer says the current directory differs if run frokxcode or the command line. Print the value of getcwd() in your program to see. The exec will open files at getcwd()/filename

Comment: The executable's directory can be obtained from `argv[0]`, passed to `main()`.

Comment: @Mike But the files are opened relative to the current directory not the path of the executable also the path of the executable in argv[0] might not be the absolute path -e.g. it could be ./exec

Comment: @Mark: Not seeing the problem. If you want to open something relative to the current directory, use a relative path. If you want to open something relative to the location of the executable, start from the executable's directory, derived from `argv[0]`, which may or may not be `.`. The point is that, unless you've changed the current working directory since start of execution, `argv[0]` will have the information needed to get to the executable's directory from the current working directory.

Comment: @Mike the issue is getting the directory the data is in.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell Xcode to run the executable from the directory containing the data files.

Bring up the info dialog for the target executable, and change the value for 'Set the working directory to:' to either the Project directory or a custom directory'